# How to run endpoint on express start

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API enpoint, called `/send-every-day`, which simply send a reminder via a Slack webhook. The problem is, I want it to be trigerred automatically, whenever the API is started. How do I acheive this in Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call a function at start, you can put it outside of the route to call it manually at start :

```
const dosomething = ( arg ) => {
  // do something
}

router.get('/send-every-day',(req, res) => {
  dosomething( req.body.foo )
  res.send("bar")
} );

dosomething( manually )
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean to say, it should work in all the routes?
You can use it as a middleware

create a folder named `middleware` and add that route

you can then make use of that in every route

eg:

```
router.get('/', send-every-day, (req, res) => {
  //Your code
} );


router.get('/blah', send-every-day, (req, res) => {
  //Your code
} );


router.get('/blahhh', send-every-day, (req, res) => {
  //Your code
} );
```

don't forget to export the send-every-day route and import it later